# Completely deleting an app from my iPhone to download a clean copy

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ipad, applications

I'm trying to delete the Firstrade (financial brokerage) app from my iPhone 8 (iOS 12.3.1) so that I can re-purchase it cleanly from the App Store.

I believe the app I originally purchased was somehow corrupted during original download. The app works on my iPad but does not start on my iPhone, only flashes the splash screen.

How do I get rid of the suspected corrupted copy and download a clean copy of the app? After I delete the the app from my device by going to Settings app → General → iPhone Storage → Firstrade: Trade, Invest, Save, the App Store always shows it with a down-arrow-cloud.

Does anyone know of a way to completely and fully delete this (any) app?

Comment: The app will always show with the cloud-arrow in the App Store because it's been downloaded once already on that same Apple ID.  Uninstalling an app with [this method](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207618) removes all files from your device.  What happens when you re-download the app to your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

That arrow just means that you have downloaded that app before and it is linked to your purchase history.

> But you may have also found apps that have a cloud icon in place of the price, and you might be wondering why. This indicates that the app has already been purchased with your Apple ID (This includes free apps. Even free apps are “purchased”, they just have no cost.) Once you have purchased an app with your Apple ID, you own that app forever, whether you choose to delete it at some point in the future or not.

https://www.solveyourtech.com/cloud-icon-next-app-app-store/

Comment: OK. Thank you. I have deleted the app using all methods suggested. I now believe that these deletions have cleaned out any corruption. I have re-installed the app from the App Store. Unfortunately, the app still behaves the same way — brief flash of an incomplete splash screen then disappears from view. At this point I must assume the app is broken for iPhone 8 iOS 12.3.1. Works fine on iPad Air 2 with same iOS. Firstrade has had this problem since Jun 1, 2019 with no progress. And no relevant comments in the App Store besides mine. Next stops: Apple Support and Firstrade (again).